# Erro ao inserir tipo blob com procedure em Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, procedure, blob, console-application

Estou tentando gravar um arquivo formato tipo Base64 em uma coluna tipo Blob do Oracle e ocorre esse erro: `"Bind de parâmetro inválido"` , o que estou fazendo errado ?

Esse é o parametro que está provocando o erro:

```
param = null;
param = new OracleParameter("p_PdfArquivo", OracleDbType.Blob);
param.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
param.Value = "CeDmaW0WYEB31xkNh0RidWQwTE8REMf1hYZN";
lstParametros.Add(param);

OracleCommand cmd = this.Conn.ExecutaComParametros("SP_PROC1", lstParametros);
```

Essa é a tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE TAB_CLI 
       (    "ID" NUMBER, 
        "DETALHE" VARCHAR2(500 BYTE), 
        "PDFARQUIVO" BLOB
       )
```

Essa é a procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "SP_PROC1" 
(
  p_iD         in number 
, p_Detalhe    in TAB1.detalhe%type  
, p_PdfArquivo in TAB1.pdfarquivo%type
) is
begin

      p_id := SEQ_TAB1.NEXTVAL ;
       insert into TAB1 ( 
              ID 
            , detalhe 
            , pdfarquivo
            ) 
       values(
              p_id 
            , p_Detalhe
            , p_PdfArquivo
            ); 
end SP_PROC1;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: o blob é um campo binário, precisa ser um array de bytes por exemplo no lugar de uma string... tente fazer o encoding da string para array de bytes

Comment: Obrigado pela dica @Ricardo Pontual, fiz a conversão: `byte[] textoAsBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("valorString");`  porém ocorre outro erro: `{"Erro Oracle ORA-12571 encontrado"}`, fiz uma pesquisa rapida na internet e vi que pode ser o antivirus da máquina ? será que procede essa informação ? Se sim será que tem como contornar  esse problema ?